# Split function on componentDidMount lifecycle's response -- React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am working on `React-redux` and using `axios` to call `APIs`.

One of the key in the `API` object has multiple value (`API` response below). I want to split that value by comma, but since `render` function ran first and then `componentDidMount`, it always throw me an error of `Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`.

I tried following things:

1. Save the value in `redux reducer` and then use split.
2. `Async await` for `componentDidMount`.
3. Tried some conditions in `shouldComponentUpdate` to ran after the data is fetched.

Is there any alternate way to load the data, manipulate it and then `render` gives us output?

API response

```
{
    "name": "user",
    "value": "ABC, XYZ"
}
```

In one of my component I use the split function in following way:

```
{this.state.userDetails && this.state.userDetails.value.toString().split(",").map(r=> <option>{r}</option>).join("")}
```

Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a null check on your response string. like `if (string && string.length > 0) {string.split}`

show some placeholder until your response arrives.